# applyForce to a node according to its rotation

Tags: swift, rotation, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I work with Xcode 6, SpriteKit and Swift,

I have a SKSpriteNode which is the default Spaceship image of a new Xcode project. This spaceship have a physicbody, but is not affected by the gravity, I want to simulate the space.

I want that when I tap the screen, a force is applied to the node so the spaceship can go forward. The problem is when the spaceship has rotated and I try to apply a force, the spaceship will not go forward like I want, but in the direction of the force applied, which is normal.

I want to know if there is any way to apply a force to a node according to its zRotation ? So no matter in which direction will be the spaceship, it will always go forward.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/57368/trigonometry-game-programming-sprite-kit-version-part-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't give it a try right now, but it should work :

```
// grab the spaceship rotation and add M_PI_2
var spaceShipRotation : CGFloat = spaceShipNode.zRotation
var calcRotation : Float = Float(spaceShipRotation) + Float(M_PI_2);

// cosf and sinf use a Float and return a Float
// however CGVector need CGFloat
let intensity : CGFloat = 10.0 // put your value
let xv = intensity * CGFloat(cosf(calcRotation))
let yv = intensity * CGFloat(sinf(calcRotation))
let vector : CGVector = CGVectorMake(xv, yv)

// apply force to spaceship
spaceShipNode.physicsBody?.applyForce(vector)
```

You have to work with math, or more precisely with trigonometry, which includes : PI, cos, sin, ...
I'm not really confortable with all of that, especially without being to try right now, but as I've told it should work. Let me know !

Comment: Yes it works perfectly ! I knew that I could do it using trigonometry, but I wanted to know if there were a method in spritekit which could allow me to do it directly, but thanks !

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but I'm new to SpriteKit too. I'll add an answer if I find a native method. Meanwhile, or if it doesn't exists, and you need to use that often : you might want to extend `SKPhysicsBody` in order to add your own method, something like _applyForceForward_.

Comment: Yes it could be a great idea, but I would like something more like a method which call a CGVector and a CGPoint, and calculate the direction of the new vector and the position of the new point according to the node's zRotation, I'll try it but I don't know if I have the skills to do it yet, first I'm going to take a look at your code and try to understand it

Comment: There is a method `applyForce:atPoint:` ( http://goo.gl/287Bfx ). But I'm not sure the result is the same, it might include angular rotation when applied. Can't try right now, let me know if you give it a try ! If the result is the same, cool. Overwise, you'll be able to create your own method sometime ! :)

Comment: I already tried it, that's the first thing I did, and it doesn't include the angular rotation. I tried to implement my method (I edited my first post), but it doesnt seems to work...

Comment: I think you should edit back you first post, as the initial question was answered. And open a new question, this time specifying the "atPoint", in order to receive new answers. I'll give it a look later on if I find the time :')